# NodeJS: Debugging RailwayJs with node-inspector

Tags: node.js, railway.js, node-inspector

Currently i'm working on an NodeJS app building over RailwayJS framework. I would like to have a node-inspector kind of debugger for step-by-step debugging of RailwayJS app. Can anyone suggest me how to use node-inspector(or any similar debugger) along with RailwayJS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Moved to super cool framework GeddyJS. It also has provision for debugging through node-inspector. Please follow the below link for more details.

https://github.com/mde/geddy/wiki/Debugging